# Integration by Substitution question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I just wanted to check if I did this question correctly or if I made a mistake when calculating $\frac{du}{dx}$ [image]

Comment: I didn't check your work, but your substitution helps very little. You end up integrating a sixth degree polynomial anyway.

Comment: Looks great! I disagree with Git Gud; the substitution allows you to avoid having to expand a fourth degree polynomial by instead just expanding a second degree polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation is correct as written.  The approach you used is better than binomial expansion of the $(1-x)^4$ term, since that would give five separate terms to integrate after distributing the $x^2$, rather than three terms as you obtained in your solution.

Personally, I would take the result and factor it to obtain $$-\frac{1}{105}(1-x)^5(1+5x+15x^2) + C.$$